# Could nanites give us superhuman strength?

Tags: humans, science-in-society, nanotechnology, bio-mechanics, super-powers

Year 2067 C.E. could nanotechnology and bio-engineering one day bestow upon us incredible strength, enable anyone to bench press[1] 1 tons without assistance at 1g Earth surface gravity? No exosuit[2] no Belgium Blue steroid[3] no DNA splicing[4] and no wand[5]. If so how does it work?

1 - an upper strength training exercise that usually involves pressing a weight upwards from a supine position.
2 - a wearable powered mobile machine.
3 - no drug.
4 - no hybrid.
5 - no magic.

Comment: Do you want it to work? If you do then (1) make a list of the components of the human body which are too weak in their natural state, and then (2) imagine how to make them strong enough.

Comment: You have asked two questions. The title asks could nanites give superhuman strength. The last sentence asks how. Which question do you want answered?

Comment: I think that they are a one and the same question. How is meaningless, if it is impossible. And if it is possible, it must somehow be so. Fairly self-evident, so only one of them could make a better question.

Comment: Answer template: *Yes*, *magic*... Honestly, you have almost 9k rep and you still continue asking plenty of questions that could be great if you didn't just *slur* them out and instead spend some time on them before....

Comment: @dot_Sp0T: what do u mean? I'm positive u must have mistaken me for someone else, many people often said I look generic...

Comment: The biggest problem with this type of questions is that a technology advanced enough is like magic. It's more about creating a solution that sounds feasible. It is important to specify this, and especially so, if there is some other constraints than just sounding nice. Nobody knows about future in 50 years, and assumptions about a certain technology may effect the other stuff about technology. Thus it is not story-wise too good of an idea to write about stuff that is not understood. Existence of nanites effects the materials in overall; not only bio-tech.

Comment: You allow for "bio-engineering" but disallow "DNA splicing" (how is that even supposed to work?). You mention a year but in the same breath ask "could one day X happen?". Said year is less than two generations into the future. What gives?

Comment: @MichaelKjorling: it was intentional because usually DNA splicing involves 2 different organisms's DNA... in short I shall forbid Chimeras!

Comment: @user6760 Well, in that case I feel you should be more explicit in the question itself. Say something like "genetic engineering is allowed, but incorporating DNA from other species is not", rather than merely "no DNA splicing".

Comment: @MichaelKjorling: working on it right now.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, with a caveat.

They would have to supplement the weak points of the human body in addition to providing enhancement to the muscles.  You may have the physical strength to bench press a ton, but what would happen to your body in the process?

Would the tendons tear right off?  Would bones snap?  Would your joints dislocate?  Yes to all of the above unless the nanites also provided the necessary secondary reinforcement to the human body.

On TV tropes, this is outlined and discussed extensively under "Required secondary powers."  I would give this a good study if I were you.

http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/RequiredSecondaryPowers

Answer (score -1):

**Plausible**

In https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Muscle you can find about muscles and how they work. With nanites building strings similar to muscle, you could get better results than with muscles, which also need to live. Or somehow they could strengthen the existing tissue.

Muscle-fibers are specialised to different type of stress: fast but weak, slow but strong and something between. With nanites they could be always of the optimal type. Thus the nanites need not to have even a better performance than the normal-muscle fiber, because they can change the type thanks to being nanites, rather than living tissue.

Comment: " bench press 1 tons" requires not only muscle fibers. It also requires much stronger bones and tendons.

Comment: That can also be achieved by nanite strings. But with bone it does have a problem. But a nanite that builds up a crystal structure could solve that. Bones are extremely strong with vertical stress, but break easily horizontally.